# Objective-C code recognized as Swift code in Swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6

I imported the objective c class I wanted to use into my bridging header but once I did, Xcode seemed to recognize the objective c code as swift code. What should I do to tell Xcode that the class is an Objective c class?

[image]

Comment: Did you imported UIKit ?

Comment: Could you post the contents of your bridging header?

Comment: The sames's happening to me. Apparently just after updating to XCode 6.3.1 yesterday. I also reported the error as it's in my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977549/xcode-trying-to-compile-objective-c-libraries-as-swift
I'd appreciate a solution too much, as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have gotten the file type wrong in XCode.

- Click the folder icon on the left to switch to the project navigator in the left pane
- Select the header file UIImageView+PlayGIF.h
- Click the file icon on the right to switch to the file inspector in the right pane
- Check and possibly fix the type of the file

The correct file types are:

- "Default - C Header" for header files with extension .h
- "Default - Objective-C Source" for Objective-C files with extension .m
- "Default - Swift Source" for Swift files with extension .swift