# Xcode trying to compile Objective-C libraries as Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a iOS Swift Project on Xcode.

I've been working on it for a long while using external Objective-C libraries on my Swift code with no problem.

Suddenly, after Xcode got updated (I guess), I try to run my project and apparently it's trying to compile de external Objective-C as Swift, so, of course, it fails.

I attach an screenshot with the errors:

[image]

And this is my Bridging Header:

```
#define degreesToRadian(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
//#import <Facebook-iOS-SDK/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <Bugsnag.h>
#import <M13Checkbox.h>

#ifndef VideoCloudBasicPlayer_VideoCloudBasicPlayer_Bridging_Header_h
#define VideoCloudBasicPlayer_VideoCloudBasicPlayer_Bridging_Header_h

#import "BCOVPlayerSDK.h"

#endif
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I had similar (but different ;-) issues and got fixed them with clearing the Derived Data in Library.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKilian How do I do that?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I did it already. It didn't work :(

Comment: Do your bridging header's match the format specified here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work before due to I'm using Parse as my first Cocoapod dependency. So I erased it from my Podfile and installed it by drag and drop style.

Then, just after that my final solution to my issue when working with Cocoapods dependencies was to delete everything (except Parse), update the Cocoapods to the latest version, reinstall everything (while Xcode is closed).

PD:
The solution above works perfectly when using Drag-and-drop installed libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. I had the same issue before.

After trying to clean and remove derived data, I fixed it by removing the old obj-c libraries and re-adding them to my project.  There may be a setting in target to tell the ARC to read objective c, but I never found it.

My Obj-c libraries somehow lost their target membership and thought it was swift.

Commit your changes.  Save your bridging header and remove the library and re-add the library, File - New - Target - (make sure Obj-C is set as language), then add your class files to the directory.  It should compile...

Comment: What do you mean when you say "add your class files"?? You mean I should create an independent Cocoa Touch Static Library as target and put the pods over there along with the non-pods libraries?

Comment: Oh, didn't know you used cocoapods to import/manage your libraries.  I'm not familiar with cocoapods.  I try to stay away from third party managers in xcode.   The way I imported my library was to drag and drop the .h and .m files (class files) into my newly created target.

Comment: I guess it's not much different from the classic drag and drop method. In fact I'm importing several libraries that way too. So, I should create a Cocoa Touch Static Library as new target of the project and put my external libraries over there?

Comment: Yes.   It's worth a shot because that's how my obj-c library compiled correctly. Commit your files and give it a shot.   If it doesn't work, discard the changes.  I spent time before looking for a setting to switch to obj-c and couldn't find it, so I just reloaded the libraries.

Comment: I wish I could charge apple for all the time I've spent fixing my code after their xcode updates.  I know they could afford it.

Comment: Garret. The target should be "Cocoa Touch Framework" or "Cocoa touch Static Library"?. Cuz the static one has no choice of language as you stated before.